# Product id already selected to delete but the product data is still on Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux-saga

I am implementing the delete product function by redux-saga and this is my deleteProduct function code

```
import firebaseApp from "./config";

const firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database();

export const deleteProduct = (productId) => {


return firebaseDb
    .ref("products")
    .child(productId)
    .remove()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Deleted ${productId}`)
      return { status: "ok" }
    })
    .catch(() => ({ status: "error" }));
}
```

After I run click to delete button, it already shows that the product id has been deleted, but the product data doesn't delete from the database.

This is my `reducer`

```
const deleteProductRequest = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true,
  type: action.type,
});

const deleteProductSuccess = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: false,
  product: action.data,
  type: action.type,
});

const deleteProductFailure = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: false,
  error: action.error,
  type: action.type,
});
```

And this is my `saga`

```
export function* deleteProductRequest(action) {
  try {
    const { productId } = action;
    const response = yield call(deleteProduct, productId);

    if ((response.status === "ok")) {
      yield put(Creators.deleteProductSuccess(response.product));
    } else {
      yield put(Creators.deleteProductFailure(response.error));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Creators.deleteProductFailure(error));
  }
}
```

My container is like this

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Creators } from "../../actions/productAction";
import ProductTable from "../../pages/ProductTable";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.product.products,
  product: state.product.product,
  loading: state.product.loading,
  error: state.product.error,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...Creators,
};

const PostNewContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProductTable);

export default PostNewContainer;
```

First of all, I get all list of product from Firebase to a Table, and then I start to implement product action and step by step to API, reducer, and Saga

Anyone understand on this case, could you please support me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`firebaseDb.ref("products").child(productId)` is a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) and a `Reference` does not have a `removeValue()`method.

You should use the [`remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove) method as follows:

```
return firebaseDb
  .ref("products")
  .child(productId)
  .remove();
```

Comment: Thank for your comment. But my product doesn't deleted. How can I delete from id and also product data. I have update my question above. Please could you help me to check it

Comment: Also, when updating your question, please don’t entirely replace your initial question because future readers will not understand the corresponding answers anymore. Please add the new content after the initial question content.